# how to receive unsolicited hl7 messages using hapi simple server?

Tags: hl7, hapi

I'm trying to develop a simple hl7 server using the hapi library, based on this example: http://hl7api.sourceforge.net/xref/ca/uhn/hl7v2/examples/SendAndReceiveAMessage.html

I can send a query message to another, I get the acknowledgement on the socket used to send the QBP^Q22, but had no luck receiving the query response on a seperate port. I've tried to follow the above example as closely as possible, and tried replacing the SimpleServer with TwoPortServer, but that didn't seem to work any better.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, there are two fields in the MSH segment that allow you to tell the client and server which ports to communicate over.  From what I can tell about the message that you are hard coding, these two ports are not shown.  In order to follow the HL7 standard, I recommend figuring out how those two fields are used.

Comment: Hi, afraid I don't follow your answer - which MSH fields? btw, I ended up working around this by patching ca.uhm.hl7v2.app.Reciever, which sufficed for my modest purposes

Comment: It looks like my answer is irrelevant to what you were trying to accomplish.  Glad you solved your problem.